# Wait element By iOSXCUITFindBy

Tags: automation, appium, appium-android, appium-ios, appium-java

I need to add in my declaration a way to wait the element, for so then  to click it. I am using Appium with Java, in a IOS device.

```
 @iOSXCUITFindBy (xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"Enviar depois\"]")
private RemoteWebElement BtnEnviarDepois;


public void ClickBtnEnviarDepois(){
    **// I need to Add a way to wait the element here**
    BtnEnviarDepois.click();
}
```

I need to add in the declaration something like this, but I don't know how to implement:

```
public void wait(By ID) {
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverFactory.getDriver(), (180));
   WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable((ID)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to initialise wait and reuse it in the page objects is to use the concept of Inheritance. Here's one example how you can do it.

Page class:

```
public class MyPage extends BasePage {
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"Enviar depois\"]")
    private WebElement btnEnviarDepois;

    public MyPage(AppiumDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    public void ClickBtnEnviarDepois(){
        waitForElementToBeClickable(btnEnviarDepois).click();
    }
}
```

BasePage class:

```
public class BasePage {
    private final WebDriverWait wait;

    public BasePage(AppiumDriver driver){
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }

    public WebElement waitForElementToBeClickable(WebElement element){
        return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
    }
}
```

Some people don't like to write custom methods like waitForElementToBeClickable(). So alternatively, you can slightly change the code as below:

Page class:

```
public class MyPage extends BasePage {
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(xpath = "//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"Enviar depois\"]")
    private WebElement btnEnviarDepois;

    public MyPage(AppiumDriver driver){
        super(driver);
    }

    public void ClickBtnEnviarDepois(){
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(btnEnviarDepois)).click();
    }
}
```

BasePage class:

```
public class BasePage {
    protected final WebDriverWait wait;

    public BasePage(AppiumDriver driver){
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't how to express my gratitude. I needed it for my work. Thanks.